# AWS update Task Image Tag on update

Tags: amazon-ecs

I can currently deploy to AWS ECS from below a docker image using a CI/CD pipeline

```
aws ecs update-service --service  --cluster  --no-force-new-deployment --region
```

Yet this uses the same image tag as pre-defined by the task, how can I update the image tag when deploying to AWS ECS in update service?

Update:

Using Bamboo you can create a JSON file to create a new image and then inject your variables during the build using: =${bamboo.buildNumber} for example

Please visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can update the image for your service by registering a new task definition and then specifying the new task definition when you call UpdateService.

```
aws ecs update-service --service $service --cluster $cluster --region $region --task-definition $newTaskDefinition
```